# converting single dimensional array to multidimensional in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array with each column consisting of `<td></td>` , probably something like this

```
$array = array('<td>1</td>','<td>2</td>','<td>3</td>','<td>4</td>','<td>5</td>'......);
```

I have to convert them into table with each row having 3 columns , each

example

```
<table>
 <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
 <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td></td>.........</tr>
</table>
```

So I will do something like this

```
 <table>
    foreach($array as $td)
    {

        //do something 

    }
    </table>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: array_chunk($array, 3)

Answer (score 2):

Just use a counter.

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $td)
{
    echo $td;
    if($i % 3 == 0 && $i < count($array)) {
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
    $i++;
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeChunks($array)
{
     $tr = array();
     for($i=0;$i<count($array)/3;$i++)
     {
        $tr[$i] = array_chunk($array, 3);
     }
     return $tr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_chunk to split array per 3 items

```
 $array = array('<td>1</td>','<td>2</td>','<td>3</td>','<td>4</td>','<td>5</td>');
?>
<table>
<?php    
    foreach(array_chunk($array,3) as $tr) 
      echo '<tr>' . implode('', $tr) . '</tr>' . "\n ";
?>
</table>
```